# I have run out of alternatives for alternate row colours in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, colors, row, alternate

[image]

I am getting the attached output in SSRS for alternate row colours. I have tried the following three versions of coding for them:

v1: `=IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "#e2efd5", Nothing)`

v2:

```
=iif(runningvalue(Fields!NominalReference.Value,COUNTDISTINCT,"Details") mod 2 = 0
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=0,"#4f81bd", Nothing)
,IIF(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2=1, Nothing, "#4f81bd"))
```

v3: 
Private bOddRow As Boolean
'*************************************************************************
' -- Display green-bar type color banding in detail rows
' -- Call from BackGroundColor property of all detail row textboxes
' -- Set Toggle True for first item, False for others.
'*************************************************************************

```
Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, _
         ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean) As String
    If Toggle Then bOddRow = Not bOddRow
    If bOddRow Then
        Return OddColor
    Else
        Return EvenColor
    End If
End Function
```

For the first column that controls the color:

```
=Code.AlternateColor("#e2efd5", Nothing, True)
=Code.AlternateColor(Nothing, "#e2efd5", True)
```

For the remaining columns, don't toggle with the third argument:

```
=Code.AlternateColor("#e2efd5", Nothing, False)
```

You may need to switch the colors in the first column in a matrix.

So, as you can see all the main versions on Stack have been tried. Therefore any ideas people might would be very welcome.

Comment: If you are using grouping or matrix, It is hard to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are applying the background color to the row containing your details group:
[image: details row]

I use this expression for my background color:

```
= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#EFF4FF", "White")
```

[image: properties panel]

Comment: @ supergrady Apologies for the late response. The answer you provided is version 1 of my query above.

Comment: Are you sure you applied the background color to the details row? Because in your screenshot it looks like the background highlighting is dependent on the value of the column.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It really doesn't like it.